# How to turn off Windows Phone if it is unresponsive and has an internal battery?

Tags: battery, soft-reset

Today my Samsung Focus hung while installing an app. When I pressed the bottom hardware buttons, it vibrated, but there was no feedback on the screen.

I held the power off button but nothing happened. So I removed the battery.

**So this is my question**: What if your phone has an internal battery (like some Lumias)? How can you work around this? Does Windows Phone have some magical combination of keys that are like holding the Power button on a computer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This article](http://www.ukmobilereview.com/manufacturers/m-nokia/reset-nokia-lumia-800/) describes that you can do a ...

1. **soft reset** in whichever state the phone is, which is in essence a battery pull.

   [image]
2. **hard reset** while turned off, which starts you over without data (so back it up if you go this way).

   [image]

Other phones probably have their own instructions on doing this; if there is somehow no way at doing this, the only thing left to do is waiting for the battery to deplete, quite unfortunate...

Comment: Interesting. Occasionally my Focus would get locked up somehow and removing the battery for a while was the only solution. Sometimes, when i plug in my Lumia 900, it gets into this weird state where it vibrates, screen turns a grayish-white for a few seconds, then black, then vibrates, then the screen turns grayish-white, then black, vibrates, etc. until i unplug it. This soft reset may come in handy. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, using Soft Reset, i managed to boot up the phone again.

Comment: My Lumia 920 occasionally has issues with the touch screen after a second-rate repair job; today it wouldn't respond to ANY input. Holding for 10 seconds just put it in standby, holding volume and power for nearly as long resulted in a vibration and a power off.

Answer (score 7):

I have found my lumia 900 will do a "battery pull" by holding down the power button for 10 seconds. I find this works much better than the 3 button solute mentioned below.

As a side note, it has worked on a Samsung Focus, and HD7. I wonder if it is pretty standard across the board.

Comment: Did you try in your phone and it works? I did the same in my Samsung Focus and it works. I don't know if in Lumia 800 you really need to do what @tom-wijsman said.

Comment: Yeah, I had to figure it out sometime last week. Worked great

Comment: Works on the Lumia 610 as well (same instructions as for Symbian N8)

Comment: Holding the power button for 10 seconds seems to work on most Windows Phone if not all. I can confirm this for Lumia 510, 640.

Answer (score 2):

I know some devices, like the htc radar, have an internal battery and you can still do a "battery pull" by pulling down/off the sim card door. There are two contacts on the door  that complete the circuit. So, in essense you are doing a battery pull by sliding down the door and breaking the circuit.

Comment: thnxxx a lot this helped me a lot .... :)

Comment: Same with the HTC 8X