# How do you remove a primary email account (e.g. hotmail, or other)

Tags: email, microsoft-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Can I Change My Live ID?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-can-i-change-my-live-id)

I have several email accounts on a second WP7 phone. My wife now uses it, so I want to remove my Hotmail account from it.

The only option when you hold down on the email account is `Sync`. I gather this is because it is the primary account, otherwise it should show "Delete" as a second option.

How do you replace or remove a primary email account?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever passing a phone to someone new to use, I'd recommend a hard reset, which, for the Nokia Lumia can be achieved by pressing the buttons as below (when the phone is turned off):

[image: Photo demonstrating how to perform a hard reset]

This will leave the phone "as new" for your wife (in this case) to set up using her own primary account.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your e-mail account is the main account on that Windows Phone, you will need to [reset your phone to change the Live ID](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-can-i-change-my-live-id). On the Nokia Lumia you can alternatively [reset like this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/382/how-to-turn-off-windows-phone-if-it-is-unresponsive-and-has-an-internal-battery/384#384):

[image]

**Note that you will lose all your data if you do this, [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) anything you still need...**

Comment: God. Three answers in less than 15 sec. WOW

Comment: @VitorCanova: Spread the word.  Beta sites get closed if they don't perform well.

Comment: @Will thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

I think that to remove the primary e-mail (Live ID) is doing a Hard Reset. You will lose all data.

Answer (score 1):

Only with Hard-Reset.
The primary Hotmail account it's impossible to delete, only sincronization is possible