# How to turn off Windows Phone (Lumia 925) with a broken screen

Tags: buttons, screen

I broke my Lumia 925's screen. The screen is black but the phone seems to be on and otherwise working.

For example, back/start/search button lights are turned on when I press the power button and my alarms work (sound is played etc.). Pressing back/start/search buttons gives feedback and side buttons seem at least to do something (for example pressing volume down stops the alarm). Don't know it the screen receives touch events. At least I haven't been able to do anything with the screen (have been trying to turn off the alarms, for example)

Now, I'd like to get the SIM out of the phone to be able to use it on another phone. To be safe, I'd like to turn off the phone first. However, I don't know how to do that without screen.

There are instructions for soft & hard reset in the question "[How to turn off Windows Phone if it is unresponsive and has an internal battery?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/382/how-to-turn-off-windows-phone-if-it-is-unresponsive-and-has-an-internal-battery)". However, soft reset is reboot and hard reset should be done when the phone is turned off. So i can't use either to turn off my phone.

**Is there a way to turn off the phone with the buttons only, without touch screen?** Or must I just wait until the phone runs out of battery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to shut down a phone without using the touchscreen or removing the battery, sorry. So you might have to wait until the battery runs out.

However the SIM card should not become damaged if you take it out of the running phone (no guarantees).

Comment: By a side example: If you take off USB pendrive / SD card from PC too early, Windows will warn you, that there is a chance, that some files were lost or card / device could be damaged. If you, however, take off SIM card from phone running Android, no such warning is present, so I assume, that you're right and that SIM card should not be damaged during such operation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Long press on Volume down + Power  button (Together)? This will shut down generally the phone if it hangs.

Comment: This actually doesn't shut the phone down but triggers a soft reset meaning the phone will boot up again afterwards.

Comment: @Thomas Assuming, that even on fastest phone Windows requires 3-5 seconds at least to boot up, I'd say, that you can remove your SIM card without any worries during initial boot sequence. Let's say in about first 1-3 seconds after performing soft boot. I'd very surprised, to learn, that Windows is doing anything around SIM card during boot phase, until system is fully loaded up.

Comment: Probably. Still, the SIM card should be just fine taking it out of a running phone. Regarding the actual question, this answer is incorrect.